# Go to a referenced cell when clicking "ok" in the message box

Tags: excel, vba, goto, msgbox

So my code starts on a different sheet with a button click. The code below stops the user from continuing with an error message if the user does not put in a value in cell "B38" on the "Pricing checklist" sheet. Is there a way to bring the user to the cell so they can input a value?

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pricing checklist").Range("B38").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the Sales Rep. " _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit and try again.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: `range("b38").select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Select a Cell Using `Application.Goto`

- [`Application.Goto method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.goto)

```vb
Sub CheckPrice()
    
    Dim PriceCell As Range
    Set PriceCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pricing checklist").Range("B38")
    
    If Len(CStr(PriceCell.Value)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Sales Rep. " _
            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit and try again.", vbCritical
        Application.Goto PriceCell, True ' to not scroll, remove 'True'
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```